# Is using !# for AJAX URLs the standard when it comes to SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, url, web-crawlers, ajax

Will URLs like this `site.com/!#users` only be crawled by Google's search engine bots, or is this a standard adopted by all search engines (e.g., Yahoo, Bing, DuckDuckGo, etc...)?

Comment: using history.js you can avoid appending # to the url while dynamically changing url

Comment: @JobinJose that actually needs html5 API as i can see, but anyway thank you for the advice ;) it's a really good product

Answer (score 1):

Bing, which powers Yahoo, [does support Google's standard](http://searchengineland.com/bing-now-supports-googles-crawlable-ajax-standard-84149). There is no indication that Duck Duck Go does.

Answer (score 0):

DuckDuckGo does appear to support this in addition to Bing.

The site [imelda-immobilien.de](http://www.imelda-immobilien.de/) has no "static" pages, they're all ajax driven. A search on [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=imelda%20immobilien%20site%3Awww.imelda-immobilien.de&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=imelda%20immobilien%20site%3Awww.imelda-immobilien.de) and [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=imelda%20immobilien%20site:www.imelda-immobilien.de) shows multiple ajax urls in the results. Yahoo is powered by bing, and a [yahoo search](http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=imelda%20immobilien%20site%3Awww.imelda-immobilien.de) shows the same results.